# Why my Jquery popup plugin isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, popup, magnific-popup

I'm using this magnific pop up plug in (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)

This is my very basic html, I simply want the button to open a pop up window in that page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    </script>-->
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

    <title>Burn That Burger</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/unsemantic-grid-responsive.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" media="all">

</head>

<body>
   <div id="popup">
    test pop up goes here
    </div>

    <button>create and show popup</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('button').magnificPopup({
        items: {
            src: '#popup',
            type: 'inline'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the debug output window of say Chrome (F12)?

Comment: You've got some issues with your HTML, there is a close `div` with no open `div`

Comment: Thanks guys, I changed it to a div but still no luck

Comment: You also appear to have a broken script tag at the top `</script>-->`. The JSFiddle below works fine, so you obviously have additional problem with the general page structure. Try running under the Chrome F12 debug tools and see what it says.

Comment: If you want to sort this out, you also need to keep feeding back information to everyone's responses. Low activity is one reason *new users* do not get any answers at all :)

Answer (score 1):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vGAsL/19/

you have applied the popup id to your body, instead of a separate div.

```
<body>
<div id="popup">
    test pop up goes here 
</div>
<button> create and show popup </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue in your body tag, it should be:

```
<body>
<div id="popup">
test pop up goes here 
</div>
```

Comment: Argh... Pipped at the post. Was sourcing a JSFiddle for magnific pop :)